# How to get selected value from select options in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning AngularJS and trying to implement a form. I have a select element and I want to be able to change the color of selected value based on the text selected.

**Html:**

```
<select ng-model="myselect" ng-class="{defaultoption: myselect.value == 'Default'}">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Default</option>
    <option>Opt1</option>
    <option>Opt2</option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
.defaultoption:{color:gray}
```

But this is not working. What can be the issue here?

**Edit1:** The default option should be greyed when selected and even when the user has opened the drop down list. Rest other options should have their black color text in both conditions (on selection and drop down list shown).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default option sets the value of the `select` model (i.e. `myselect` here) to an empty string `""`, and `undefined` - if set to the model - would map to that default.

So, you could do this:

```
ng-class="{defaultoption: !myselect}">
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5JTmXzBT4x45VnYCmMt?p=preview)

Comment: I tried this, and though this is working fine, but when the menu is opened, it is also shown gray now. How to make sure that only the value in the box is colored?

Comment: @Sam, then you need to set `ng-class` to an `<option>`, rather than `<select>`

Comment: But that only changes the color of options and not the text when it is selected and is showing on the combobox.

Comment: @Sam, clearly the confusion here is because you haven't accurately defined what you wanted in the question. Define the CSS that you want applied under different conditions - we'll help you with Angular

Comment: @Sam, is this something that you could even do with CSS? If so, define it for both cases. Right now this is "do this for me" question

Comment: Yeah, I did it with CSS. Added style to each option so that their color remains black.

Answer (score 0):

Use :-

```
ng-class="{'defaultoption': myselect.value == 'Default'}"
```

And css shoud be

```
 .defaultoption{
         color:gray
      }
```